# mysqli_affected_rows for UPDATE sometimes returns 0 on full row match

Tags: php, mysql

Say, if I have MySQL query to update a row:

```
$res = mysqli_query($link, 
    "UPDATE table SET val=1 WHERE id=5");

if($res)
{
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0)
    {
        echo("Updated something!");
    }
    else
        echo("Didn't update");
}
else
    echo("Error");
```

How do I change it to distinguish between these 3 conditions:

1. Found item with `id=5` and set it.
2. Did not find item with `id=5`.
3. Error

In the way it's written now, if my database column `val` already has `1` in that row, `mysqli_affected_rows` will return 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mysqli_info`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php) to get the information you need to distinguish between the two cases. `mysqli_info($link)` after an `UPDATE` query will return a string something like

```
Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0
```

which you can then parse, for example using `preg_match`:

```
// $info = mysqli_info($link);
$info = 'Rows matched: 12 Changed: 8 Warnings: 0';
preg_match('/Rows matched: (\d+) Changed: (\d+)/', $info, $matches);
list(, $matched, $changed) = $matches;
echo "$matched rows matched, $changed rows changed\n";
```

Output:

```
12 rows matched, 8 rows changed
```

You can then use the values in `$matched` and `$changed` to distinguish between your two cases.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. But are you sure that it will always return that string in English? I'm always hesitant to rely on string outputs like that.

Comment: @c00000fd you could just ignore the letters and use `/[^:]+: (\d+) [^:]+: (\d+)/`

Comment: Or even `/[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)/`

Comment: It looks like work around. Sad, that php doesn't have any solution for this.

Comment: @Dylan unfortunately it's a limitation of the interface; you can either get back the number of rows that were matched or the number of rows that were changed, there's no way of getting both values back for one query other than this workaround.

Comment: @Nick: Agree, one way is to make another database call for the record to check for its existence.

Comment: @Dylan true, and that is probably the most reliable way. The downside is that it's another database query that has to be executed.